# How do I pass in a number to web3.eth().block()?

Tags: rust, ethereum, rust-web3

I'm using the [rust-web3](https://github.com/tomusdrw/rust-web3) crate to connect to an ethereum node and get information about a block by it's block number (or block height). Based on [this example](https://github.com/tomusdrw/rust-web3#example) here is how I was able to implement it:

```rust
use web3;
use web3::types::{BlockId, BlockNumber, U64};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> web3::Result<()> {
    let transport = web3::transports::Http::new(WEB3_URL)?;
    let web3 = web3::Web3::new(transport);

    web3.eth().block(BlockId::Number(BlockNumber::Number(U64([42]))));
    Ok(())
}
```

Is there an easier way to pass in that **42** to `web3.eth().block()`?

Right now I'm using two enums and the `U64` struct to make a variable that the compiler accepts. I'm new to rust and I think I'm missing an important concept of the language that would simplify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an `impl From<U64> for BlockId` ([source](https://docs.rs/web3/0.16.0/web3/types/enum.BlockId.html#impl-From%3CU64%3E)), so you can shorten the call a little:

```
web3.eth().block(U64([42]).into());
```